# PHP: why does whenever i edit it does not allow me to change the value in select box

Tags: php, html, ajax, select

whenever i select an option in my select box it automatically display the value in the text box in the create.php

here is the code of the create.php

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="sub_category">Category:</label>
  <select class="form-control select_group" id="sub_category_1" name="sub_category[]" onchange="getSubCategoryData(1)">
    <option value=""></option>
    <?php foreach ($sub_category as $k => $v): ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $v['id'] ?>"><?php echo $v['name'] ?></option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </select>
</div>


 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="markup">Markup:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="markup" name="markup" disabled autocomplete="off" placeholder="Markup">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="markup_value" name="markup_value" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

then it's working fine just like i wanted to.

[image]

as you can see in this photo i the category is a select box and whenever i select an option the markup will be displayed based on the category data

script in create.php

```
function getSubCategoryData(row_id)
{
  var sub_category_id = $("#sub_category_"+row_id).val();    
  if(sub_category_id == "") {
    $("#markup").val("");
    $("#markup_value").val("");

  } else {
    $.ajax({
      url: base_url + 'products/getSubcatById',
      type: 'post',
      data: {sub_category_id : sub_category_id},
      dataType: 'json',
      success:function(response) {
        
        $("#markup").val(response.markup);
        $("#markup_value").val(response.markup);

      } 
    }); 
  }
}
```

bet when it comes to editing in a scenario of i want to change the category because i input an mistake data it does not process, in my edit.php wherein i can edit the fields in this module i can edit the name the cost and etc.. but i cannot edit the category whenever i try to change the category to others it does not allow me to click it and the markup value stays what value i have in the early data entry

example is that i have 2 category 1 is starter and 2 is drinks my first category has a markup of 50 and the second one is 60 so whenever i data entry an data and i want to change it's markup it does not allow me to change the category and my markup and i can't seem to know what is my problem here.

here is my edit.php code

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="sub_category">Category:</label>
  <?php $sub_category_data = json_decode($product_data['sub_category_id']); ?>
  <select class="form-control select_group" id="sub_category_1" name="sub_category[]" onchange="getSubCategoryData(1)">
    <?php foreach ($sub_category as $k => $v): ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $v['id'] ?>" <?php if(in_array($v['id'], $sub_category_data)) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>><?php echo $v['name'] ?></option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </select>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
    <label for="markup">Markup:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="markup" name="markup" disabled 
      value="<?php echo !empty($this->input->post('markup_value')) ?:$product_data['markup'] ?>" 
      autocomplete="off" placeholder="Markup">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="markup_value" name="markup_value" 
      value="<?php echo !empty($this->input->post('markup_value')) ?:$product_data['markup'] ?>" 
      autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

and the ajax or script in the edit.php:

```
function getSubCategoryData(row_id)
{
  var sub_category_id = $("#sub_category_"+row_id).val();    
  if(sub_category_id == "") {
    $("#markup").val("");
    $("#markup_value").val("");

  } else {
    $.ajax({
      url: base_url + 'products/getSubcatById',


      type: 'post',
      data: {sub_category_id : sub_category_id},
      dataType: 'json',
      success:function(response) {
        
        $("#markup").val(response.markup);
        $("#markup_value").val(response.markup);

      } 
    }); 

  }
}
```

and yes i can see the data input earlier if i input an category 1 with a markup with 50 it does save in the field but whenever i edit it and change the category i cannot click on the select box and the markup does not change.

Please watch this video:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lFNCyxoFegyTJNoULrSs59ZsYa_rjNs3/view?usp=sharing

i'm having a hard time clicking the category when i tried to change and the markup does not change

in case the video does not work here i uploaded it in yt

https://youtu.be/52SYwU8y30A

Comment: I do not understand the problem. Can you create a JS snippet in your question that would make the problem reproducible?

Comment: "...does not allow me to change the category..." Are you saying the select list is disabled? It won't open? Or it opens but when you select an option the select list does not change? Please elaborate. The video doesn't play. Can you upload it to youtube instead?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles https://youtu.be/52SYwU8y30A

Comment: in browser DEV tools, console, do you see any errors?

Comment: i can see that you can change category in youtube video while editing. The problem is not clear

Comment: `url: base_url + 'products/getSubcatById',` i cant see variable `base_url` declared here. if you are trying to use codeigniter function base_url() than use like `url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>products/getSubcatById",`

Comment: @LeenaPatel wow that solved the problem can you please answer it so that you can received the bounty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `base_url` should be declared as javascript variable. You can assign PHP `base_url()` to `base_url` variable like this

```
var base_url = "<?php echo base_url() ?>;

url: base_url + "products/getSubcatById",
```

OR you can directly add like this too without declaring javascript variable

```
url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>products/getSubcatById",
```